# increased body temperature during meditation

Tags: personal-practice, samatha

Is it common during samatha for the body temperature to rise enough to cause  some isolated forms of sweating? Specifically around the head, like where a hat would set and sometimes across the upper chest and shoulders?

It doesn't happen every time but at least several times a week. The room temperature is well regulated and in no way warm. I also noticed that there may be a correlation to some insomnia on the same nights that the sweating occurs during the meditation.

Comment: A few checkpoints during the meditation session: do you force your breathing, or you breathe naturally? Do you keep your back straight but your shoulders, arms and legs are relaxed? Do you fix your attention to a single point, like the nostril tip or the abdomen, and not let the mind wandering elsewhere?

Comment: Occasionally I find myself somewhat controlling my breath. Primarily when I revert to counting to regain focus. I fix my attention at the base of the nostrils where the philtrum and nose sort of meet and where I can feel the breath. For the most part my back is straight with arms, legs, shoulders and hands relaxed...though at times I have to consciously relax them as I will feel myself become a little ridged because I tend to slouch a bit.

Comment: Try to breathe naturally all the time. Keep the body straight but relaxed all the time. Also pay attention to wandering thoughts. Normally once one's gotten "into the zone", meaning one's reached that deep absorption state where one's able to single-mindedly focus on that single meditation object without distractions, most of the problems naturally go away. So don't worry too much, keep practicing diligently. Once you're in "the zone", the problem will be gone by itself.

Answer (score 1):

There's all kinds of wackiness that can occur during meditation.  Some of it is mental, some of it is somatic, and still other phenomenon are a blend of the two.  None of these things are any reason for concern and it's best not to pay them much mind.  Some of these experiences will come and go while others are will appear quite regularly almost becoming like your own personal brand of meditation.  To be honest, elevated body temperature is actually pretty tame compared some of the other stuff that can happen.  Just wait until your skull twists into a spiral, your hands inflate to the size of beach balls, and you suddenly find yourself sitting at the lunch table on the 117 day of fifth grade!

Answer (score 1):

If you have worked with some activity before the meditation, such as walking outdoor, doing home, your sweat have to come out your body when you start to sit in meditation, to cool down your body.

Every body movement is making  [activation energy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Activation_energy). All activation energy give the temperature. Human body must be 37 degree Celsius to woking fine, so the body try to cool itself down when it's no activity such as sitting meditation.

I recommend to slow down and cool down your body before meditation.